# How to select shapes using vba in an already created Visio drawing

Tags: vba, shapes, visio, visual-studio-macros

I have a Visio drawing and I want to be able to Select shapes from it and paste them to other sheets depending on certain variables.

What is the code for selecting the different shapes on the page.  I am trying this but it is not working.

```
Dim vsoSelection As Visio.Selection
vsoSelection.Select Visio.Shape(1), visSelect
```

What am I missing here?

and also is it possible to get the strings entered into text boxes into Visio?

Comment: What do you mean by the "Strings entered into text boxes"?  Do you mean the text of a shape, or do you mean textbox controls added to a page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you're getting an error because your vsoSelection object is nothing.  So you need to do:
Set vsoSelection = ActiveWindow.Selection